# In Java, how would I print a 2d array that resembles a seating chart with an 'aisle' down the middle?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, 2d

I am working on an assignment where I have to print a 2d array that resembles a seating chart. Each element has a number, and increases in number when you go through the array, and also has an "aisle" down the middle where no one can sit. Below is what the array should look like.

```
1  2  3  x 4  5  6 
7  8  9  x 10 11 12
13 14 15 x 16 17 18
19 20 21 x 22 23 24
```

This would continue until there are 48 total seats. This would make it have 8 rows and 7 columns.

Right now my code is bad. I tried to make the code that would substitute the fourth column of the code with xs, but that did not work. Here is what my code looks like so far. My code only prints 0s when it runs. How would I make my code actually print the xs, and could I have some pointers on how to make each element display its respective number?

```
public class airplane {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] rows = new int[8];
        int[] columns = new int[7];

        int[][] chart = new int[rows.length][columns.length];

        for(int j = 0; j < rows.length; j++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < columns.length; k++)
            {
                if(columns.length == 4)
                {
                    chart[j][k] = 'x';
                }
                System.out.print(chart[j][k] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

I apologize if my code is bad. I am inexperienced, and I do not have much help at all right now.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This is not a free homework service and you need to demonstrate you are making a strong attempt at working through you problem on your own.

Comment: Please post your [attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) and refer to [how to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/3284624)

Comment: I edited my post, so hopefully it works better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done as below with 2 for loops where first loop iterate column wise and second iterate row wise

```
public class Print2DArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int seatNo = 1;
        int row = 8;    // set row count
        int column = 7; // set column count

        int[][] print2DArray = new int[row][column];  // init your 2d seat matrix

        for (int i = 0; i < print2DArray.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < print2DArray[i].length/2; j++) {
                System.out.print(seatNo++ + " ");
//                System.out.print(print2DArray[i][j]++ + " ");  // You can use this line to print the value on the current position in the array position
            }
            System.out.print("x ");
            for (int j = 0; j < print2DArray[i].length/2; j++) {
                System.out.print(seatNo++ + " ");
//                System.out.print(print2DArray[i][j]++ + " ");  // You can use this line to print the value on the current position in the array position
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```